# d3.timeFormat on domain has only 1 value

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js, visualization, heatmap

I am trying to replace dayofweek integer to its corresponding names.

[image: My Heatmap so far]

```
var y_label = [...new Set(data.map((item) => item.y))].sort(d3.descending); // [0 - 6]

// Build Y scales and axis:
const y = d3.scaleBand().range([height, 0]).domain(y_label).padding(0.01);
svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

Now I am adding `.tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%A"))`

```
var y_label = [...new Set(data.map((item) => item.y))].sort(d3.descending); // [0 - 6]

// Build Y scales and axis:
const y = d3.scaleBand().range([height, 0]).domain(y_label).padding(0.01);
svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%A")));
```

What I get is this:

[image: Heatmap with same names]

I dont even know where the Thursday comes from.
How do I fix my code?

Comment: What is your input data format?

Comment: `1: Object { x: 11, y: 1, value: 1405 }

​2: Object { x: 11, y: 0, value: 1356 }

​​3: Object { x: 11, y: 3, value: 1329 }

​4: Object { x: 11, y: 4, value: 1284 }

5: Object { x: 11, y: 6, value: 860 }`

Comment: `y` is always 0 to 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you construct a `Date` object from a number, it takes the value as number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 00:00 (Thursday).
Thus, any number from 0 to 6 is interpreted as very beginning of that day.
Don't use `d3.timeFormat`. Instead just define:

```
const weekDays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];

....call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickFormat(d => weekDays[d.y]);
```